# Writing forwarded rsyslogs to journald to be able to filter them by SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER?

Tags: logging, systemd, ubuntu-server, rsyslog, systemd-journald

Hello StackOverflow Gods/Regulars/Users !

I am currently working on a logging system for two applications running on my servers.

Here is the context :

- Server dev1 : Ubuntu server 18.04 (freshly installed)

  - is running a systemd.service algo-ep

```
    [Unit]
    Description="Algo EP"
    [Service]
    Type=simple
    User=me
    WorkingDirectory=/home/me/bin
    ExecStart=/home/me/bin/AlgoEp
    StandardOutput=syslog
    StandardError=syslog
    SyslogIdentifier=dev1_algo_ep
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- is running another systemd.service algo-mdw

```
    [Unit]
    Description="Algo MDW"
    [Service]
    Type=simple
    User=me
    WorkingDirectory=/home/me/bin
    ExecStart=/home/me/bin/AlgoMdw
    StandardOutput=syslog
    StandardError=syslog
    SyslogIdentifier=dev1_algo_mdw
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- Server dev2 : Ubuntu server 18.04 (freshly installed)

  - is running a systemd.service algo-ep

```
    [Unit]
    Description="Algo EP"
    [Service]
    Type=simple
    User=me
    WorkingDirectory=/home/me/bin
    ExecStart=/home/me/bin/AlgoEp
    StandardOutput=syslog
    StandardError=syslog
    SyslogIdentifier=dev2_algo_ep
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I wanted to be able to read the log of each service when I ssh on dev1 using journalctl (systemd-journal).

Like this:`journalctl -t dev1_algo_ep -t dev1_algo_mdw -t dev2_algo_ep`

So, I added a `rsyslog.d/algo-ep.conf` on dev2:

```
if $programname == 'dev2_algo_ep' then {          
        action(type="omfwd"                       
           queue.type="linkedlist"                
           queue.filename="algo_fwd"              
           queue.saveOnShutdown="on"              
           action.resumeRetryCount="-1"           
           target="dev1" port="514" protocol="tcp"
        )
}
```

and added `rsyslog.d/algo.conf` on dev1:

```
module(load="imtcp")
module(load="omjournal")

ruleset(name="remote-dev2") {
        action(type="omjournal")
}

input(type="imtcp" port="514" ruleset="remote-dev2")
```

At this point, no problem, I got the line in journalctl with `journalctl -r`:

```
Nov 23 13:27:47 dev1 dev2_algo_ep[3142]:[15246]:  Ep Server listening on localhost:10001...
Nov 23 13:27:47 dev1 dev2_algo_ep[2421]:[15246]:  Ep Server stops...
[...]
```

But when I try `journalctl -t dev2_algo_ep`:

```
me@dev1:~$ journalctl -t dev2_algo_ep
-- Logs begin at Fri 2018-06-01 13:54:11 CEST, end at Fri 2018-11-23 13:27:47 CET. --
me@dev1:~$
```

Because received log's SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER is set as `dev2_algo_ep[3142]:` instead of `dev2_algo_ep`.

So, my question : Is there a way, magical or obvious

1. to export the log from dev2 to dev1 with a specific SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER ?
2. or to receive the log on dev1 and to set a specific SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER before sending it to journald ?
3. or simply to do this ?

Thanks in advance for your advice, your help and your information !

[Edit]
It seems that the mix rsyslog + journald is very little known. I didn't found anything in the man page (except the possibility to create a template to rebuild the log at reception on dev1, but looks pretty odd to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option1
since you already got log from journalctl, you can use json format to check what field the line you want, e.g. check what value in `SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER` field.

the following line shows `SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER` is `nginx`, so you can use `journalctl -t nginx`

```
journalctl -o json
{ "__CURSOR" : "s=00000000000000000000000000000000;i=146c8;b=170127f0cd5441a3bea76fe326915bd0;m=bb5bba879;t=590367fad5ace;x=33cdab5cd2077705", "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1565938628254414", "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP" : "50293614713", "_BOOT_ID" : "170127f0cd5441a3bea76fe326915bd0", "_SELINUX_CONTEXT" : "unconfined\n", "_SYSTEMD_SLICE" : "system.slice", "_MACHINE_ID" : "4211ff3f594041f3966d836585a11a05", "_HOSTNAME" : "VM-0-4-ubuntu", "_TRANSPORT" : "journal", "_CAP_EFFECTIVE" : "0", "PRIORITY" : "5", "_UID" : "102", "_GID" : "106", "_COMM" : "rsyslogd", "_EXE" : "/usr/sbin/rsyslogd", "_CMDLINE" : "/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n", "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP" : "/system.slice/rsyslog.service", "_SYSTEMD_UNIT" : "rsyslog.service", "_PID" : "3280", "_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID" : "270801fdff7943bc83cd7cef242b3271", "CODE_FILE" : "omjournal.c", "CODE_LINE" : "270", "CODE_FUNC" : "send_non_template_message", "SYSLOG_FACILITY" : "16", "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" : "nginx", "MESSAGE" : "36.24.73.111 - - [16/Aug/2019:14:57:08 +0800] \"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1\" 200 946 \"http://111.231.88.233/todo\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36\"", "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1565938628254404" }
```

option2
if you cannot find the `SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER`, check the rsyslog input module doc. `imfile` has the `tag` parameter, so you can use `journalctl -t nginx` to get the log.
check following example

```
module(load="imfile")
module(load="omjournal")

ruleset(name="nginx") {
    action(type="omjournal")
}

input(
    type="imfile"
    File="/var/log/nginx/access.log"
    tag="nginx"
    ruleset="nginx")
```

option3

you need check `omjournal` doc, `omjournal` has a parameter called `tempalte`, which you can specify the format you sent to `journald`
check following docs.

1. www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omjournal.html
2. www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html
3. www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.journal-fields.html

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Your *option2* is just what I needed.